# Is "purchased" more formal than "bought?"

Tags: word-choice

It was suggested to me that the correct verb to use referring to something I paid for in the past is the word *purchased*:

> I purchased x.

instead of

> I bought x.

As far as I can tell, the words are almost the same in this context. The only thing I've seen online is that *boughten* is a colloquial past participle of the word *bought*.

Is *bought* ever, if rarely, considered colloquial? Is it ever improper to use when referring to a recent purchase?

---

Edit: not spoken English, and not sure how relevant, but here's an ngrams graph of "[bought vs purchased](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bought%2Cpurchased&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)."

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQXGr.jpg

Comment: No, *boughten* is not a colloquial past tense of *buy*.  It is an old past participle used strictly as an adjective, and remains current in some dialects. It's like *drink, drank, drunk, drunken* for a *drunken man* and *buy, bought, bought, boughten* for the opposite of a homemade item: a ***store-boughten*** one.

Comment: Ah, updated. Is there a styling guide for how to properly ask questions?

Comment: That's a good question, about a styling guide. I think there might be something on Meta, but it may not be complete/current.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macmillan tags *[purchase](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/purchase)* as **formal**, while their definition of *[buy](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/buy)* in the sense of of "to get something by paying money for it" has no such qualifier.

The phrase *bought it* is a colloquial or informal way of saying *killed*. But *[bought](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bought)* on its own is, as the linked definition says, simply "the past tense and present participle of *buy*."

EDIT: M-W lists *boughten* as a **dialectical** form of *bought*, and provides this delightful example:

> my red sled, and my *boughten* wagon --W.A. White

Answer (score 7):

*Bought* isn't generally considered colloquial, but *purchased* certainly is more formal. There's no reason it would be considered improper regarding recent purchases in particular, unless for some reason any shred of informality is forbidden.

It may be useful to look at the most common collocations of each in British English:

> PURCHASE PRICE
> PURCHASE AGREEMENT
> PURCHASE ORDER
> PURCHASE BEHAVIOUR
> PURCHASE GOODS
> PURCHASE MONEY
> PURCHASE SCHEMES
> PURCHASE SHARES
> PURCHASE DECISIONS
> PURCHASE AGREEMENTS
> PURCHASE TAX
> PURCHASE DECISION
> PURCHASE ORDERS
> PURCHASE GRANT
> PURCHASE LAND
> PURCHASE TERMS
> PURCHASE CONTRACT
> PURCHASE CONTRACTS
> PURCHASE NOTICE
> PURCHASE LEDGER
> PURCHASE POWERS
> PURCHASE CONSIDERATION
> PURCHASE MOTIVATION
> PURCHASE SCHEME
> PURCHASE SERVICES
> PURCHASE ARMS
> PURCHASE FUND
> PURCHASE GRANTS
> PURCHASE MONIES
>
> BUY SHARES
> BUY FOOD
> BUY THINGS
> BUY GOODS
> BUY TIME
> BUY TICKETS
> BUY LAND
> BUY EQUIPMENT
> BUY CLOTHES
> BUY BOOKS
> BUY PROPERTY
> BUY PRODUCTS
> BUY HOUSES
> BUY PLAYERS
> BUY DECISION
> BUY DRINKS
> BUY PRESENTS
> BUY STUFF
> BUY UNITS
> BUY SERVICES
> BUY BREAD
> BUY DRUGS
> BUY FISH
> BUY STOCK
> BUY COMPUTER
> BUY CONDOMS
> BUY HOMES
> BUY RECORDS
> BUY CIGARETTES

Most of the collocations for purchase have to do with business interactions, where communications and descriptions are usually formal. Most of the collocations for buy are for daily goods, which would usually be mentioned in informal conversation. Even if neither is usually explicitly identified as formal or informal, the usage pattern shows it.

Comment: I appreciate your input, but could you explain any major points to take away from this data?

Comment: Sure. Most of the collocations for `purchase` have to do with business interactions, where communications and descriptions are usually formal. Most of the collocations for `buy` are for daily goods, which would usually be mentioned in informal conversation. 

Even if neither is usually explicitly identified as formal or informal, the usage pattern shows it.

Comment: Backgammon, it would probably be useful to include that in your answer instead of just posting a comment about it.

Answer (score 4):

Where I live in the northeast USA, forms of *buy* are more likely to be heard in informal conversation than those of *purchase*, whereas you are more likely to hear *purchase* in formal situations, such as when dealing with a salesperson or financial professional. In noun form, *purchases* and *acquisitions* are used formally, as *buys* or constructs such as *things I bought* are definitely informal.

*Boughten* would normally be used as a participle; *bought* is already the past tense of buy. I think it's more archaic than colloquial, I certainly haven't heard it used much in everyday conversation.

Comment: *Boughten* is an archaic or dialectic participial form. If you ask rural Wisconsinites what the opposite of *home-made* is, a great many of them will answer ***store-boughten***.  One other thing: please, *please*, **please**, ***please***, ᴘʟᴇᴀsᴇ, *ᴘʟᴇᴀsᴇ*, **ᴘʟᴇᴀsᴇ**, ***ᴘʟᴇᴀsᴇ*** do not try to use backticks for italics or quoting on ELU: **it does not work**, and produces only reprehensibly repugnant blue monospace.  [The *use–mention distinction* is best rendered by setting in italic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use–mention_distinction), the way proper reference books do these things.

Comment: @tchrist: what's that bit of gibberish between the fourth "please" and "do not try"? All I see is [box]L[box][box]S[box], repeated 4 times.

Comment: @Marthaª It's [a 1995 thing](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/1995-06-24/), Martha. You know that.

Comment: @Marthaª Your use of "gibberish" was borderline rude. You know full well that things like code point U+1D07 ‹ᴇ› `LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL E`, are part of the Unicode Standard version 4.0, published now more then ten years ago. It sounds like you are running something with no updates this side of the Millennium, Martha, and you cannot expect everyone else to remain stuck in the Stone Age of yestercentury just because you are. Please install fonts that support modern/current Latin characters at the very least, and please use a browser and GUI with a reasonable glyph-replacement policy.

Comment: @tchrist: my apologies, I did not mean to offend you with my use of "gibberish". I merely wanted to call your attention to some text that obviously didn't come across as intended on my end. (My OS and browser are both as updated as they get. Granted, the OS is not the newest, but the newest OS from M$ is a steaming pile of horse turd, so I'm holding on to this machine as long as I can.)

Answer (score 3):

Etymology of *buy* from Dictionary.com:

> before 1000;  Middle English  byen,  variant of byggen, buggen,  Old
>   English  bycgan;  cognate with Old Saxon  buggjan,  Gothic  bugjan  to
>   buy, Old Norse  byggja  to lend, rent

Etymology of *purchase* from Dictionary.com:

> before 1150;  (v.) Middle English  purchasen  < Anglo-French 
>   purchacer  to seek to obtain, procure ( Old French  pourchacier ),
>   equivalent to pur-  (< Latin  prō  pro1 ) + chacer  to chase1 ; (noun)
>   Middle English  < Anglo-French  purchas  ( Old French  porchas ),
>   derivative of the v.

Assuming this is true, we surmise that the word purchase is "newer" to English, or that it came into usage more recently than buy.  What major event happened between 1000 A.D. and 1150 A.D.?

The Norman conquest of England. 1066 A.D. One of only a handful of things that modern-day U.S. students learn in high school, second only to that Eli Whitney patented the cotton gin.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_conquest_of_England

After this, there was a major cultural shift in the area. From the same Wikipedia article:

> One of the most obvious effects of the conquest was the introduction
>   of Anglo-Norman, a northern dialect of Old French, as the language of
>   the ruling classes in England, displacing Old English. French words
>   entered the English language, and a further sign of the shift was the
>   usage of names common in France instead of Anglo-Saxon names. Male
>   names such as William, Robert and Richard soon became common; female
>   names changed more slowly. The Norman invasion had little impact on
>   placenames, which had changed significantly after earlier Scandinavian
>   invasions. It is not known how much English the Norman invaders
>   learned, nor how much the knowledge of French spread among the lower
>   classes, but the demands of trade and basic communication probably
>   meant that at least some of the Normans and native English were
>   bilingual.

French and Latin became the only allowed languages in courts of law.  French and Romance culture in general reigned as the more "civilized" and "advanced" society. Old English speakers and Old English words were shunned and ridiculed as the language of the peasants.

---

Cut to present day, we still see this in effect in today's English.  To say that we have a *gut-ache*, would sound practically vulgar.  Instead, we use the Romance word, ***stomache***-ache.

> Origin:   1300–50;  Middle English  stomak  < Latin  stomachus 
>   gullet, stomach < Greek  stómachos  orig., opening; akin to stoma

You don't pay for things with a *writ,* you pay for them with a *check/checque*.

> Origin:   before 900;  Middle English,  Old English;  cognate with Old
>   Norse  rit  writing, Gothic  writs  letter. See write

In England and America, we don't eat *swine* — although people who speak Germanic languages still eat *Schweinfleisch*.  No no, we eat *porque*. Not swine. Swine sounds gross.

Oh yeah! Gross! Isn't that funny, considering what "gross" typically means in American and British English. It's used to describe something repulsive, whereas in German it just means... big.  However, if we want to talk about something being *large*:

> 1125–75;  Middle English  < Old French  < Latin  larga,  feminine of largus  ample, generous

So in conclusion, I would say that yes, purchase is more "formal" than buy, *especially in legal and intellectual matters*, simply because of the thousand-year-old cultural cataclysm I described.